# spring batch MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We get the below error when using spring batch .

org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=8827 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2

What I observed from different forums was that we were using org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean which is not thread safe and not adivsable to be used in production.

We do not want to persist the meta data of the jobs or use in memory database  - Is there any other alternative to MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean  ?

Thanks

Lives

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: did you find a solution on this? I have the same problem also with MapJobRepo.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/109453-optimisticlockingfailureexception-and-mapjobrepositoryfactorybean) on the spring forums the MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean is not generally intended for production use. I guess I would ask why wouldn't you want the metadata persisted to a database? It provides tremendous value, not to mention giving you the ability to use the [spring batch admin console](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/).